# OneNote API Capture webscreenshot

Tags: onenote

I am facing a challenge in One Note API web screenshot API, I am posting a reqest as mentioned below but for few content URL it is rendering as a **file icon in** one Note web application

[image: Screenshot]

```
--NewPart
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Presentation"
Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml

<html>
<head>
<title>Example 2</title>
<meta name="created" content=2016-06-22/>
</head>
<body>
<div><img    data-render-src=https://content.connect.connect-uat.co.uk/Content/UAT/ElektraMedia/Maths_Y7/MF_1.1/Contents/Ch02/1/example2.html width=700 /></div>
</body>
</html>
--NewPart--
```

kindly suggest me if any thing wrong in the web screen shot rendering?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your request with the OneNote ApiGee Console and I was able to get  the page created in my notebook.

Here is the request I tried -

```
--NewPart
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Presentation"
Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-us">
   <head>
   <title>Page from OneNote API console</title>
   <meta name="created" content="2014-03-17T09:00:00-08:00" /> 
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <img data-render-src=https://content.connect.connect-uat.co.uk/Content/UAT/ElektraMedia/Maths_Y7/MF_1.1/Contents/Ch02/1/example2.html width=700 />
</div>
</body>
</html>
--NewPart--
```